# Type NSAttributedString has no subscript members in tableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of AttributedString with X items and a tableView that will display this array, and for each item in the array there will be a Section in the table.
In the "cellForRowAt" function, if I do
"let text = arrayTexts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]", the error 'Type NSAttributedString has no subscript members' appears.
What can I do?

Declaration: `var arrayTexts = [NSAttributedString]()`

Populate:

```
let html = json["data"][order]["informations"][textIndex]["text"].stringValue
                            let textHtml = html.unescapingFromHTML


                            do {
                                let str = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: textHtml.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
                                let fullRange : NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, str.length)
                                str.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 17.0)!], range: fullRange )

                                self.arrayTexts.append(str)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
```

Comment: Show how you declare and populate `arrayTexts`.

Comment: Declaration: var arrayTexts = [NSAttributedString](). Each item is a string coming from a database, and I use "try NSMutableAttributedString (data : , options : , documentAttributes : )" to turn it into an attributedString and append in arrayTexts

Comment: Your syntax assumes an array (row) in an array (section) `[[<Type>]]`.

Comment: @vadian Yes, i try without [indexPath.section] and displayed the correct number of sections, but with the same text in all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `let text = arrayTexts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` will only work if you've got an array of arrays of NSAttributedStrings (`[[NSAttributedString]]`).  So `arrayTexts[indexPath.section]` will return a single NSAttributedString, so trying to subscript that with `[indexPath.row]` will fail.  It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do without seeing more code, but from your description it sounds like you can just change the code to `let text = arrayTexts[indexPath.section]` and it'll give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the data source array

```
var arrayTexts = [[NSAttributedString]]()
```

and populate the array

```
self.arrayTexts.append([str])
```

That creates a section for each item.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I used the other answer I got, but with your answer I learned to use better arrays in cells. Thank you so much!